# Watching for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

[please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THZKj.png)

trying to runserver and getting this error,
this error starts from moving the project folder. even i try undo button. still having the same issue. is any solution to get back normal.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text data; see [ask]. We prefer a [mcve] as formatted text (use the `{}` button) here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your `models.py` file:

1: Your import is wrong, correct is `from django.db import models`
2: And on line 5

```py
class student(models.Model):
    # your code
```

PS: Make the first letter of your class name capitalized, i.e `Student` not `student`